# Detect events from inside a WKWebView instance

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, wkwebview

I know how to detect a normal keyboard being shown in `Swift` but I'm wondering if it's possible to detect the events inside a `WKWebView` because... if the app gets in the background, inputs lose focus but the "blur" event isn't triggered.

The idea is that I have a "navigation bar" in the app which gets pushed out of  the view (upwards) when the keyboard is being shown, and I'd like to keep showing it. Knowing the keyboard is about `216px` tall I'd just like to narrow the height of the `content wrapper` which is `flex based` by `216px` but that's not really working since it is an animation which I can't really reproduce so it's smooth. I also can't detect when user went into `emoji` tab. I got rid of the `autocorrect` since I just set it to `off` for the `input` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
override viewWillAppear(){
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

func keyboardWillHide(){
  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
  var info = notification.userInfo!
  var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
  // handle your layout according to frame
}
```